# Upload a video made with mediaRecorder to the server

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, mediarecorder

Good Morning,
I'm new in Stackoverflow. Please Help me.
I need to upload the video to the server. The video is recorded using mediarecording but I cannot pass the video to the controller which will then load it. 
I would like the video to be uploaded by clicking Save button but I can't implement the code for that. I tried with ajax and also with the FormData but it didn't work.
I'm using Laravel 7 Framework.
This is HTML code:

```
    <video  muted="muted" ></video>
    <video  id="vid2"  controls></video>
    <button id="btnStart" type="button">Rec</button>
    <button id="btnStop" type="button">Stop</button>
    <button id="btnSave" type="button">Save</button>
```

This is Javascript code:

```
     let start = document.getElementById('btnStart');
        let stop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
        let save = document.getElementById('btnSave');
        let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
        let chunks = [];
        var blob = null;

        start.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
            mediaRecorder.start();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        })

       save.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{

            const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('video', blob);
         fetch('videoRec/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
            })
            .then(response => {console.log('upload success');})
        .catch(error => {console.log('error');})
});


        stop.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        });


        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
            chunks.push(ev.data);
        }
        mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
             blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : chunks[0].type });
            chunks = [];
            let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            vidSave.src = videoURL;
            const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('video', blob);
         fetch('videoRec', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
            })
            .then(response => { console.log('upload success');})
        .catch(error => {console.log('error');})
        } 
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) { 
        console.log(err.name, err.message); 
    });
```

This is the route of controller:

```
Route::post('/videoRec','VideoController@save');
```

The function of the contrller:

```
public function save(Request $req){
        $file = $req->file('video');
        $path=$file->store('avatars');
        return ['path'=>$path,'upload'=>'success'];

    }
```

Comment: When uploading a file it does not matter if it is created using `MediaRecorder`, or not.   Also: your function `Save` seems to do noting much? Did you forget to post the code that you tried to put in there?

Comment: You have a TypeError as the syntax highlighter makes clear (missing a  `'` after the POST url, this fixed, you should face a ReferenceError when clicking on `save` because `blob` is not defined.

Comment: You're right i forgot ' I corrected  thank you. I defined blob as exernal variable. I have a ReferenceError although I declared blob as an external variable, but I shouldn't have any problems. Why?
Thank you.

Comment: I put the function save in the stop.addEventListener for the moment and I havan't ReferenceError for the blob, but I need that save function works alone.

Comment: There is no external `blob` being defined here, and the one `blob` that is being defined in `mediaRecorder.onstop` will stay in this scope because of the `let` keyword.

Comment: I changed the code aobve. Now I have blob as external variable "var blob=null;" but when I click save, I have the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: blob is not defined

Comment: And you clicked on stop before clicking on save?

Comment: nono. Now I transfer all the code of the save function in stop, because of the blob's problem that I have in save function. In stop I don't have this problem so for the moment I use stop.addlistener to see if I can upload the video. Once I have successfully uploaded the video, I will solve the blob's problem. But if I can, I solve blob's problem before.
Thank you for the patience

Answer (score 2):

```js
let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' })
```

That might not work. Use the type of the first blob `chunks[0].type`.

```js
let blob = null;

mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type : chunks[0].type });
  chunks = [];
  let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  vidSave.src = videoURL;
}

save.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('video', blob);

  fetch('<url>/<controller>', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => {})
  .catch(error => {})
})
```

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) provide some examples of how to get file from formData

```php
public function save(Request $req){
  $file = $request->video;
}
```

Comment: Hello Jozef, thank you for answer me. Just a question, if I have this Route: 
Route::post('/videoRec/{data}','VideoController@save');
in the <url>/<controllor> what I have to write?  I wrote videoRec/data but didn't work.
Thank you.
Gennaro

Comment: I changed the code above. Now if I click save  I have this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: blob is not defined

If I click stop, the FormData responce "upload success" in the log, but I have this error:
videoRec:224 POST http://mycovervideo.localhost/videoRec 419 (unknown status)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolve. I put in fetch this:

```
headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
```

and the video is upload.

Thank you everybody for the help!!

Gennaro